# Adding custom text with a link via PHP function in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add additional text `woocommerce_before_checkout_form` in `functions.php` via Editor but I see following error:

> "Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 0 of
>   file Unknown. Please fix and try saving again. Exception thrown
>   without a stack frame"

```
function bonus() {
    echo "<div id='bonus'>Don't you have a coupon?<a href="https://mywebsite.com/checkout/?apply_coupon=promo5?apply_coupon=promo5">Click here to get 5% OFF</a></div>";
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'bonus' );
```

When I add only text without `ahref` everything works.

I want to add to this `ahref` redirect to: `https://mywebsite.com/checkout/?apply_coupon=promo5`

Comment: You need to escape your quotes within the string you're echoing. You could also use `'` instead. `"<a href=\"xxx\""` or `"<a href='xxx'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

You need to change `<a href="https://mywebsite.com/checkout/?apply_coupon=promo5?apply_coupon=promo5">` to `<a href='https://mywebsite.com/checkout/?apply_coupon=promo5?apply_coupon=promo5'>`

```
function bonus() {
    echo "<div id='bonus'>Don\'t you have a coupon?<a href='https://mywebsite.com/checkout/?apply_coupon=promo5?apply_coupon=promo5'>Click here to get 5% OFF</a></div>";
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'bonus' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used double quote within double quote that is the reason error is coming.

Try below code it will work.

```
function bonus() {
  echo "<div id='bonus'>Don't you have a coupon?<a href='https://mywebsite.com/checkout/?apply_coupon=promo5?apply_coupon=promo5'>Click here to get 5% OFF</a></div>";
    }

  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'bonus' );
```